# Specific heat of water

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In statistical mechanics, we derive all the thermodynamic quantities, including specific heat $c_v$ from the partition function $Z = \mathrm{Tr} \, [ \, e^{\beta H } \,]$ . For solid, we assume simple harmonic oscillator and together with Debye model, analytical solution of $c_v$ is then obtained.

So, I wonder how can we deal with a liquid system, which is a highly correlated system ? (It seems that liquid system is very difficult to handle) In particular, is it possible to derive the specific heat of water (liquid) $c_v \approx 4200  \, J \, kg^{-1} \, K^{-1}$ ?

Comment: You can certainly compute the specific heat of water using computer simulation (i.e. numerical methods)...